# CORS enable but request header got mixed up from different host

Tags: tomcat, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a tomcat 8 server with CORS enabled in the `web.xml`.
The CORS plugin works on most of the cases, but sometimes it mixes up the header request from local host and server host

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mipldevlinux7:6060/juneberry/data/blue-marbles/config.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://mipldevlinux7:7777' is therefore not allowed access
```

My tomcat server is on a server called `mipldevlinux7` at port `6060`, i have a production server on the same host on the port `7777`.

I do my development on `localhost:3000`, and my colleague runs his dev-server on `localhost:8080`.

We got CORS error, and the error mixes the headers between our localhosts to `3000` and sometimes `8080`. Sometime we even get a header request of `mipledevlinux7:7777` why we are requesting from localhost.

The CORS I am using is the build in CORS tomcat 8 provided:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Last-Modified</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is tomcat caching the request header or uses it the last request header somehow which is causing the mix-up, and blocked all the requests?

Comment: Did you try setting `cors.preflight.maxage` to `-1` ? From the [documentation flowchat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png),  if `cors.support.credentials` is true then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not set to `*` but to the origin header. In your case it might be a browser cache issue (tomcat tells the browser to cache the result of the pre-flight request for 1800 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `cors.support.credentials` to true, use `cors.preflight.maxage` to -1 to disable browser cache:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>-1</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Are you sure you want to set `cors.allowed.origins` to `*`?